# recompiling with -fPIE flag could not resolve error

Tags: c++, makefile

I am trying to compile [this app](https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/electrical-engineering-and-computer-science/6-837-computer-graphics-fall-2012/assignments/distrib.zip) using its makefile on WSL. But I get the following error:

```
g++ -g -Wall -ansi pendulumSystem.o TimeStepper.o particleSystem.o ClothSystem.o simpleSystem.o camera.o main.o vecmath/src/Vector3f.o vecmath/src/Vector2f.o vecmath/src/Matrix3f.o vecmath/src/Matrix4f.o vecmath/src/Vector4f.o vecmath/src/Quat4f.o vecmath/src/Matrix2f.o -o a3 -L. -lRK4 -lglut -lGL -lGLU

/usr/bin/ld: ./libRK4.a(RK4.o): relocation R_X86_64_32 against symbol `__gxx_personality_v0@@CXXABI_1.3' can not be used when making a PIE object; recompile with -fPIE

/usr/bin/ld: ./libRK4.a(RK4.o): relocation R_X86_64_PC32 against symbol `_Znwm@@GLIBCXX_3.4' can not be used when making a PIE object; recompile with -fPIE

/usr/bin/ld: final link failed: bad value

collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [Makefile:15: a3] Error 1
```

I tried editing my makefile to include the flag like below, but it still gives me the same error message.

```
INCFLAGS  = -I vecmath/include
INCFLAGS += -I /usr/include/GL

LINKFLAGS = -L. -lRK4 -lglut -lGL -lGLU
CFLAGS    = -g -Wall -ansi -fPIE
CC        = g++
SRCS      = $(wildcard *.cpp)
SRCS     += $(wildcard vecmath/src/*.cpp)
OBJS      = $(SRCS:.cpp=.o)
PROG      = a3

all: $(SRCS) $(PROG)

$(PROG): $(OBJS)
        $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(OBJS) -o $@ $(LINKFLAGS)

.cpp.o:
        $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $< -c -o $@ $(INCFLAGS)

depend:
        makedepend $(INCFLAGS) -Y $(SRCS)

clean:
        rm $(OBJS) $(PROG)
```

Could it be that the provided `libRK4.a` file was not compiled with the `-fPIE` flag?

Comment: Could it be that libRK4.a needs to be compiled with -fPIE? Yes, that's exactly what the linker is complaining about.

Comment: Alternatively you can leave libRK4.a as is and compile your binary with `-no-pie`.